# How to reset/clear form within my create.js.erb?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't get my form to reset correctly. It submits and it goes to the database but everything remains on the form.

Here is my code:

**DogsController**

```
def create
  @dog = current_user.dogs.new(params[:dog])
  if @dog.save
    format.js
  else
    format.js
  end
end
```

**dog/create.js.erb**

```
$('.add-dog-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'dogs/form', locals: { dog: @dog })) %>');
$('.add-dog-form > form')[0].reset(); // doesn't work
```

**dog/new.js.erb**

```
$('.add-dog-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'dogs/form', locals: { dog: @dog })) %>');
```

**dogs/_form**

```
<%= form_for(@dog, :remote => true) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.submit "Add Dog" %>
<% end %>
```

---

I create dogs at the Pets view instead of the dogs.

**PetsController**

```
  def add
    @dog = Dog.new
    @cat = Cat.new
    @bird = Bird.new
  end
```

**pets/add.html.erb**

I click on the tab which changes it to the Dog Tab using [Twitter Bootstraps Tabbable Nav ability](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs)

```
<div class="tabbable">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
         <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Cat</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Dog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Bird</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active add-cat-form" id="tab1">
         <%= render "cats/form" %>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane add-dog-form" id="tab2">
         <%= render "dogs/form" %>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane add-bird-form" id="tab3">
         <%= render "birds/form" %>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I reset the form if it gets created?

Answer (score 8):

Try giving the form an id:

```
<%= form_for(@dog, :remote => true, :html => { :id => 'dog_form' } ) do |f| %>
```

and `$('#dog_form')[0].reset();`.

Alternatively,  you can do `$(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");`.

Comment: $('#dog_form')[0].reset();

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems my error was in my files themselves. I had created the js files as partials instead of regular pages. i.e. `_create.js.erb` should be `create.js.erb`. I also had to add `respond_to do |format|` in the controller `create` action. Now I got everything working correctly.